# open an excel file on ios device

Tags: ios, html, cordova, durandal

I am developing a SPA application using `HTML5` `DURANDAL` and `knockoutjs`. I am then converting the application to native ios using `phone gap`.I have a functionality where i have to export a grid to excel. Can i  export the grid to excel or spreadsheet in ios devices.? The other option I have is to export the excel sheet on the server side and then download it on the device. Will the file open in ios device.? As per my knowledge i have to keep the file in `ONE DRIVE` and then download it. Please help as to what can be done and which will be a proper method.

Thanks

Comment: the UIWebView can open excel files, but for read only

Comment: @jcesarmobile : Thanks for the reply..can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can export using Excel XML format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx

Comment: @trojanfoe : I will be able to export the excel sheet using the link you gave but how will i open the link in ios device.?

Comment: just load the excel on the webview with a link to the file (local or remote)